# I can't send my serializable implementations through apache xml-rpc communication

Tags: java, apache, servlets, xml-rpc, serializable

Anyone know how to send my own serialized object implementations as parameter through a apache xml-rpc communication? I already have the extensions enabled on both sides but every time i try to send an own serializable implementation  an exception is fired up on client side with the message: "premature end of file". if I try send an empty array of that serializable implementation, the communication is successful done. it is something related with the content length?

Comment: Yes, someone does. The users@ws.apache.org mailing list is likely to yield a useful answer, the developer answers messages there.